# Add axis to leaflet map

Tags: r, leaflet, maps, r-leaflet

How can you add an `x` and `y` axis to a `leaflet` map figure -- in the case of a map how to add the `longitude` and `latitude`?

For the figure below, how can axis be added please?

```
library(leaflet)

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
```

[image]

Comment: You are probably looking for this leafletjs plugin https://github.com/dtutic/Leaflet.EdgeScaleBar. But it has not yet been incorporated into a leaflet R plugin (that I know of). The closest and easiest to implement is the built-in graticule plugin. https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/morefeatures.html#graticule

Comment: Thanks @rbasa. Details to extending are given at https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/extending.html. I may have a bash.

Comment: leaflet::addGraticule() gets you part way there, but only at smaller scales.